# javascript : how to create fadeIn() fadeOut() stop() function using requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, fadein, fadeout

any library in microjs doesn't seem enough. morpheus of ender also not good in fadeIn fadeOut.

Would you show how to build `fadeIn() fadeOut() stop()` function using requestAnimationFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Okay

So I will show you fadeout, given I haven't done this in a while and this will likely be a broken demonstration but you should get the idea.

```
setInterval(function(){

 var x = new Image();
 x.src = 'x.png';

 if (x.alpha >0){
   x.alpha-=.01;
 }
},100);
```

Also this only works if you already have an html5 canvas up

you should get the idea though

enjoy =]

Comment: you stop it with clearInterval...just look it up, it is easy!